# SVD of matrix of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Let $A$ be a (complex) matrix with eigendecomposition $A = U S U^{-1}$, where $U$ is the invertible matrix of eigenvectors.

What is known about the singular value decomposition (SVD) of $U$?

Comment: Hint: if $U$ a matrix of eigenvectors, then what properties must $U$ and $U^{-1}$ necessarily have?

Comment: @JonathanPal except for the fact that $U$ must be invertible, I cannot think of any property that has to hold in general (hermitian, unitary, normal, symmetric, ...)

Comment: fair enough. just to be clear, are we trying to consider the singular value decomposition of $U$, or the singular value decomposition of $A$?

Comment: @JonathanPal I'm interested in the SVD of $U$. If the understanding of this goes through the SVD of $A$ it's good enough.